# ReactJS .default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I'm new to React and Mobx so I try to do a small app. When I try to run it i get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: _releasesState2.default is not a constructor`. I'm about to bash my head in since I have no clue what the issue is. Here is what I got so far:

my index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Releases from "./components/releases";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  } 
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
           <Releases />
        </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

the releases.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

import ReleaseState from "./releases-state";

@observer
export default class Releases extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();

    this.state = new ReleaseState();
   }
   render() {
     return (
        <div>
            // content here
        </div>
      ) 
   }
}
```

and the releases-state.js:

```
import { observable } from "mobx"

class ReleaseState {
   @observable releases = [];

   constructor() {
      let data = [] // some array with data
   }
}

const releaseState = new ReleaseState();
```

Can someone maybe tell me whats wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not export the `ReleaseState` class in `release-state.js`. Try modifying your code to:

```
export default class ReleaseState {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have forgotten to export `ReleaseState`?

```
export default releaseState;
```